# using the basecamp api to create/delete tasks and add comments

Tags: php, xml, api, basecamp

I am trying to gather an understanding about what can and cannot be achieved using the basecamp api, my task is to create an extension where you can create/delete tasks as well as add comments. Can this sort of task be carried out using only xml or is a server side language such as PHP required? I am just trying to get some kind of idea of how the api can be used as I have had no exposure to it before.

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with just XML, but if you want to do it programmatically, you'd need a server-side language (like PHP) to insert the variables into your requests. The XML calls require authorization each time, and you'd need a way to reference the specific project that the tasks pertain to.

I'd recommend looking into the PHP wrapper if that's the language you're most comfortable with

https://github.com/sirprize/basecamp